# How to stop OpenVPN tunnel if server doesn't response?

Tags: configuration, openvpn, timeout

I have two openvpn servers, but both routes to the one network. It made for the fault tolerance. If one of them is down traffic should go via another one. Clients receive routes with different metric, so this task is solved.

But when one of the servers goes offline, client try to reconnect to this server and doesn't turn off tun-interface. So traffic tries to go via problem server.

I want to client turns off tun-interface when server goes offline and automatically turn it on when server turns back.

This is client's config:

```
tls-client

dev tun
proto udp
remote server1.ovpn.example.com 2100

topology subnet

pull

#resolv-retry infinite
#nobind

tls-auth keys/ta.key 1
ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/client.crt
key keys/client.key
ns-cert-type server

cipher DES-EDE3-CBC

keepalive 10 120

comp-lzo

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn.log

verb 3

route 172.19.20.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.150.3
route-metric 3
```

I think if I remove `keep-alive` the tun-interface will goes offline after ping timeout, but will it turns back when server return?

Comment: Your question does not seems to be clear, shouldn't just a matter of having multiple servers, with infinite resolv be enough? `remote server1; remote server2;  resolv-retry infinite`. Tun will keep trying until it finds a healthy openvpn server...

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `persist-tun` option.  Without that option, then the VPN link goes down, the tun device will close and be removed.  The problem of course is that removing that option means that you need to run your VPN daemon as root instead of nobody.  Because as nobody account, OpenVPN will not be able to create a new tun device when the connection is re-established.

Answer (score 1):

After creating my VPN project [for Qubes](https://github.com/tasket/Qubes-vpn-support), I discovered OpenVPN has a definite tendency to hang when a connection goes down.

Here are the options I've added to make OpenVPN responsive to disconnections:

```
ping 10
ping-restart 40
connect-retry 5 30
connect-retry-max 7
resolv-retry 15
```

According to the docs, if you have multiple `remote` entries then upon connection failure ping-restart will cause the next remote to be used. Therefore, specifying multiple `remote` lines for your servers could be useful here.

Comment: Does this go into client or server config?

Comment: I guess it is the client config, because he is talking about the option to set multiple remotes, and the remote is configure in the client config file.